# Setting a field as Not NULL in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I can't find where I can set a field as NOT NULL in phpmyadmin. I would like to have alse my database controlling this feature. I am doing this programatically but I believe that this could add an extra layer of security in my system.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When editing the field in the Structure tab, look for the "NULL" checkbox. When un-checked, this is the equivalent of the `NOT NULL` statement.

Answer (score 17):

[image: not null in php my admin]

If you **uncheck** this property then it means that it is **not null**.

Comment: UX/UI designer for phpMyAdmin needs a new day job, lol.