# PHP empty string error for mysql date column with null value

Tags: php, mysql, date, null

I have an HTML form with an input field `(type="date")` and a mysql DB with a column with datatype `"date"` that accepts null when I do the query directly in phpmyadmin.

Also when I select a date in my html form (using browser default date picker) the query runs correctly. But when I leave the mentioned input blank, the following error is shown "Incorrect date value: '' for column '`received_date`'.

Any help to get rid of this issue is appreciated.

Here are the sql and DB/Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE customer.tbl1 ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , usrname
VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL , received_date DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL , PRIMARY
KEY (id)) ENGINE = MyISAM;

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl1 (usrname, received_date) VALUES ('$usrname',
'$received_date')";
```

Comment: check `if (empty($_post['date']))? NULL: $_POST['date']` and then do query

Comment: Can you share the SQL query you're using along with the schema from that table?

Comment: In my query I used variables like INSERT INTO TBL1 (username, received_date) VALUES ('$usrname', '$received_date')...

I think the single quotes that I use to surround the variable causes the problem. Because I replaced the variable with NULL (without quotes). It worked. But I cannot use the NULL in my query permanently because the date field is optional that may or may not have date selected.

Comment: in question, you are talking about `SELECT` and here you are providing `INSERT`. very confusing. Please add HTML+CODE in your question to clarify your problem.

Comment: With select I meant choosing date from the browser default date-time picker. Because in the HTML form the input type is date.

Comment: I will say change column default value from NULL to current timestamp or DateTime. The issue will be solved automatically. Also at the time of searching `NULL` will create an issue when you are trying to sort them.

Comment: Please provide your html code and database file, so we can check and replay you.

Comment: I added the code

Comment: In your application, is a blank date a valid input?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all.
The following solved the issue:

```
if (empty($received_date)) {
            $received_date= 'NULL';
}
```

However, before posting the problem here I tried this (if condition) with NULL without the single quotes but It didn't work. Now the single quotes solved the issue.

Comment: used the same but in my case it was NULL without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your application: Is Null a valid value for your data?

If that's ok, then update your database schema to allow Null values (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35963275/3341745).

If you don't want this value to be Null, then the database check is doing its job. In this case, you should validate the data on the web page before the user is allowed to submit it (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp).